# Unable to SaveAsTextFile AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'saveAsTextFile'

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have submitted a similar question relating to saveAsTextFile, but I'm not sure if one question will provide the same answer as I now have a new error messagae:

I have compiled the following pyspark.sql code:

```
#%%
import findspark
findspark.init('/home/packt/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7')
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('ops').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv('/home/packt/Downloads/Spark_DataFrames/Person_Person.csv',inferSchema=True,header=True)
df.createOrReplaceTempView('Person_Person')
myresults = spark.sql("""SELECT
  PersonType
 ,COUNT(PersonType) AS `Person Count`
FROM Person_Person
GROUP BY PersonType""")
myresults.collect()
result = myresults.collect()
result
result.saveAsTextFile("test")
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Append ResultsClear Results
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-9e137ed161cc> in <module>()
----> 1 result.saveAsTextFile("test")

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'saveAsTextFile'
```

As I mentioned I'm trying to send the results of my query to a text file with the command saveAsTextFile, but I am getting the above error.

Can someone shed some light on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Collect() returns all the records of the Dataframe as a list of type Row. And you are calling 'SaveAsTextFile' on the result which is a list.

List doesnt have the 'saveAsTextFile' function, so it's throwing an error.

```
result = myresults.collect()
result.saveAsTextFile("test")
```

To save the contents of the Dataframe to file, you have 2 options:

1. Convert the DataFrame into RDD and call 'saveAsTextFile' function on it.

   `myresults.rdd.saveAsTextFile(OUTPUT_PATH)`
2. Using DataframeWriter. In this case, DataFrame must have only one column that is of string type. Each row becomes a new line in the output file.

   `myresults.write.format("text").save(OUTPUT_PATH)`

As you have more than 1 column in Dataframe, proceed with Option:1.

Also by default, spark will create 200 Partitions for shuffle. so, 200 files will be created in the output path. If you less data, configure the below parameter according to your data size.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 5) # 5 files will be written to output folder.
```